# Querying UPS API to find out how much they charged me for a shipment: Is it possible?

Tags: api, ups

I'm working on an application that integrates with several of UPS's APIs, but there's one piece of information I can't figure out how to retrieve: how much UPS charged us to ship a package.

This information is available through the UPS web app, and I can't see in principle why it shouldn't be available programmatically. Is it?

NB: I know that you can send UPS information about the shipment and get back an *estimated* shipping cost, but that's not what I'm after. What I would like to retrieve is that actual shipping cost for a shipped package, specifically the "Public Charge", "Incentives", and "Net Amount" values listed on UPS invoices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can actually get to the billing/invoice data from the standard [ups developer kit](http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/techsupport/developercenter.html?WT.svl=SubNav). You can get the shipment charges, etc, at confirmation time through the shipment accept API, but it doesn't sound like that is what you are looking for. To get to billing data you have to [enroll in a separate program](https://www.ups.com/viewbill/enroll) for CSV/XML/EDI access.

Comment: "enroll in a separate program" link is dead